# Javafx can not set element field to AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with a javaFX project.

I have a fxml including another one :

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1200.0" prefWidth="1600.0" stylesheets="@../css/mainWindow.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.MainWindowController">
    <children>
        <BorderPane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="1200.0" prefWidth="1600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <top>
                <ListView fx:id="gameMenu" onMouseClicked="#handleGameMenuClick" orientation="HORIZONTAL" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1600.0" style="-fx-background-color: orange;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
            </top>
            <left>
                <ListView fx:id="planetMenu" onMouseClicked="#handlePlanetMenuClick" minHeight="1100.0" minWidth="200.0" maxHeight="1100.0" maxWidth="200.0" prefHeight="1100.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" />
            </left>
            <right>
                <ListView fx:id="empireMenu" onMouseClicked="#handleEmpireMenuClick" minHeight="1100.0" minWidth="200.0" maxHeight="1100.0" maxWidth="200.0" prefHeight="1100.0" prefWidth="200.0"  style="-fx-background-color: red;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
            </right>
            <center>
                    <fx:include fx:id="mainElement" source="MainElementView.fxml"/>
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In the controller, I use

@FXML
  private MainElementViewController mainElement;
To access to the included element

Here is the MainElementView.fxml :

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@../css/specificElement.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.MainElementViewController">
    <children>

    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The ode of MainElementViewController.java :

```
package com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement;

import com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.specificelement.SpecificElementViewController;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author olivier
 */
public class MainElementViewController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  SpecificElementViewController specificElement;

  private List<String> elementTypesList;

  public MainElementViewController() {

  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
  }

  public List<String> getElementTypesList() {
    return elementTypesList;
  }

  public void setElementTypesList(List<String> elementTypesList) {
    System.out.println("plop");
    this.elementTypesList = elementTypesList;
    specificElement.setElementTypes(elementTypesList);
  }

}
```

And here is the SpecificElementView.xml :

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1200.0" stylesheets="@../css/specificElement.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.specificelement.SpecificElementViewController">
    <children>
        <ListView fx:id="elementTypes" onMouseClicked="#handleSpecificElementClick" orientation="HORIZONTAL" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1200.0" style="-fx-background-color: purple;" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And the java :

```
package com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.specificelement;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 *
 * @author olivier
 */
public class SpecificElementViewController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {

  private List<String> elementTypesList;

  @FXML
  private ListView elementTypes;

  public SpecificElementViewController() {
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
  }

  @FXML
  public void handleSpecificElementClick(MouseEvent arg) throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Not implemented yet!!!");
  }

  public List<String> getElementTypes() {
    return elementTypesList;
  }

  public void setElementTypes(List<String> elementTypesList) {
    this.elementTypes = elementTypes;
    elementTypes.getItems().clear();
    for (String s : elementTypesList) {
      System.out.println("type : " + s);
      elementTypes.getItems().add(s);
    }
  }
}
```

When i run it, I have an exception :

> avafx.fxml.LoadException: 
>   /home/olivier/spaceOpera/Client_V2/target/classes/fxml/MainElementView.fxml:15
>   /home/olivier/spaceOpera/Client_V2/target/classes/fxml/MainWindow.fxml:27
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   com.spaceopera.client.Client.startGame(Client.java:88)    at
>   com.spaceopera.client.Client.start(Client.java:62)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)2018-11-11 20:10:11 ERROR
>   LoggerTool:32 - Error starting main window : 
>   /home/olivier/spaceOpera/Client_V2/target/classes/fxml/MainElementView.fxml:15
>   /home/olivier/spaceOpera/Client_V2/target/classes/fxml/MainWindow.fxml:27
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set
>   com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.specificelement.SpecificElementViewController
>   field
>   com.spaceopera.client.ihm.mainwindow.mainelement.MainElementViewController.specificElement
>   to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)  at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.injectFields(FXMLLoader.java:1163)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$1600(FXMLLoader.java:103)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:857)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:751)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)    ... 19 more

If I remove the include in MainElementView.fxml,  I have the same exception on the include in the MainWindow.fxml (with problem to set MainElement to anchorpane instead of specificElement).

Can you help me to fix this pls?

Comment: You need to append `Controller` to the `fx:id` to get the name of the field where the controller of the `<fx:include>` element is is injected. If you use the `fx:id` itself as field name, the object created for the root elment of the included fxml is injected.

Comment: I lost 4 hours because of that...
Thanks for your help I didn't know the "controller" was important in the name.